# losing scope data outside $http service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new in angularjs and i have a problem trying to use $scope inside a $http.
inside $http i can see data but outside service i get null.

Console.log($scope.data) inside service I get data:

[image]

Console.log($scope.data) outside always null:

[image]

mycode :

```
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', 'ServicePatient', function ($scope, ServicePatient) {
    $scope.data = null;
    ServicePatient.all().success(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    });
    $scope.sortType     = 'last_Name'; // the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // the default sort order
    $scope.search  = '';     // the default search/filter term
    $scope.filterEnabled = '';
    $scope.setEnabled = function(status){
    $scope.filterEnabled = status;
    if(status){
      angular.element(document.querySelector( '#enabledFalse')).removeClass('active-btn');
      angular.element(document.querySelector( '#enabledTrue')).addClass('active-btn');
    } else {
      angular.element(document.querySelector( '#enabledTrue')).removeClass('active-btn');
      angular.element(document.querySelector( '#enabledFalse')).addClass('active-btn');
    }  
  }

  console.log($scope.data);

  }]);

  app.service('ServicePatient', ['$http', function ($http) {
    function all() {
      return $http({
        url: 'http://54.165.192.65/ekare/ws6.php?request=patient',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    }

    return {
      all: all
    }
  }]);
}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

Comment: That is because ajax call is asyncronous

Comment: @PSL thanks how I can fix that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Cool how you passed the angular module into the IIFE as 'app'. Never seen it done that way before.

Comment: @PSL that aout avascript generally I mean with angularjs

Comment: @ELMEKKIAnouar angularjs is javascript and the concept of being "asyncronous" remains the same.

Comment: @shmuli the problem is with asyncronous

Comment: controller shouldn't be used for DOM manipulation, use `ng-class` for that and bind to scope model values